# How to style a scrollbar to set it's colour and stop it fading out

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am working on a WinRT application and I have a problem with a scrollbar that needs to be made more noticeable on a white background, and needs to stop disappearing.
The user is meant to answer a number of questions displayed by the listview and at present can easily miss that there are more questions off the end of the screen.
So I would like to style my scrollbars accordingly.
What I find out as a newcomer to XAML is that the solutions I have found online involve a huge amount of code and it is hard to work out from that the very simple things that I want to do.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="*" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
        <TextBlock Text=" = Required " FontSize="20"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Survey.SelectedSection.Questions, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                SelectionMode="None"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                Background="White"
                ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResourceKey=QuestionDisplay}"
                ItemContainerStyle=
                    "{StaticResource ResourceKey=QuestionListViewItemContainerStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

So how do I set the colour of the scrollbars and stop them from fading out?

Comment: It disappears even when you have `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` set to `Visible`? That should make it persistent in staying there and visible, but if you want it too look differently then you'll have to get in and edit the `Style` template of it.

Comment: OK, well I start with <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">

    </Style>. But what property sets the colour of the scrollbars? And what property would stop them from fading out?

Comment: The attached property setting of `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` should keep it persistently visible. However you could always dig into the Style template of ScrollViewer, then into it's embedded Scrollbar control templates and remove the fade animations and do whatever you like to them. Although it will take some mid-level template customization I think to get everything you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can get the default styles from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj710190.aspx

To put my own colours in I just changed the SolidColorBrush elements. And to stop the scrollbar disappearing I commented out;

```
<VisualState x:Name="NoIndicator">
    <Storyboard>
        <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" TargetName="HorizontalPanningRoot" />
        <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" TargetName="VerticalPanningRoot" />
        <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" TargetName="HorizontalRoot" />
        <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0" TargetName="VerticalRoot" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```